# PHP/HTML - Cache disabled yet still caches?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, caching

I've got a back-end admin pannel which has various buttons which when clicked opens up a sweet alert JS and then uses AJAX to modify the DB however when the button are pressed and AJAX returns "Success" the buttons should change color however they don't the code for no-cache is the following:

```
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I believe it is to with the JS after the AJAX executes as it reloads the page with:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Just a quick note: The page that needs to have no-cache depends on a GET request e.g mysite.com/admin.php?acc=1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by "a POST variable" you refer to the "?acc=1" in that URL you gave as an example then you should sit down and read a bit about http request methods.

Comment: Whether the color of your button changes has most likely nothing to do with any caching issue or protocol detail. That is a question of your own client side logic. Since you did not post that there is nothing we can say to help with that.

Comment: Sorry a bit bad of explanation by me, long day. Meant to say that the acc is set by GET from another page which when the page is loaded SQL Queries are ran and determines the button color, for example: $AccStatus and depending on the $AccStatus either 1 or 0 it'll change the color of the buttons. I know it does work as CTRL + F5 works perfectly fine.